# Is there a similar origin for the words 'atom' and 'item'?

Tags: etymology

It seems the words ***atom*** and ***item*** are similar sounding words, and have similar letter structure.

In meaning, they have similarities as well, where ***atom*** means *small unit that can no longer be divided* and ***item*** means *small unit in a collection*.

My question is: **Is there a similar origin for the words 'atom' and 'item'?**

Comment: In Google type "etymology atom" and "etymology item".  Compare the results.

Comment: Well ... how about 'atom' & 'adam'?

Comment: Well ... one is Greek for can't be cut; the other is Hebrew for earth.  So I'm gonna guess different origins.

Comment: @LittleEva- how ’bout Adam and Edam?

Comment: @Jim No relationship.  Edam is a town in the Netherlands so named because it started near a dam on the River E.  I'm not making this up.

Comment: And if you specifically want word origins, this is called _etymology_. Look on Etymonline:  http://www.etymonline.com

Comment: @deadrat-  Really??  And I was so sure that because they each had 4 letters and a ’d’ in them they must have come from the same root...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their etymology, they have no common origin:

[Item](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=item&searchmode=none):

> - ***late 14c. (adv.) "moreover, in addition," from Latin item (adv.) "likewise, just so, moreover," used to introduce a new fact or statement, probably from ita "thus," id "it" (see id) + adverbial ending -tem (compare idem "the same").*** Thus "a statement or maxim" (of the kind formerly introduced by the word item), first recorded 1560s. Meaning "detail of information" (especially in a newspaper) is from 1819; item "sexually linked unmarried couple" is 1970, probably from notion of being an item in the gossip columns.

[Atom](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=atom%20&searchmode=none) (n.)

> - ***late 15c., as a hypothetical indivisible body, the building block of the universe, from Latin atomus (especially in Lucretius) "indivisible particle," from Greek atomos "uncut, unhewn; indivisible," from a- "not" + tomos "a cutting," from temnein "to cut" (see tome)***. An ancient term of philosophical speculation (in Leucippus, Democritus), revived 1805 by British chemist John Dalton. In late classical and medieval use also a unit of time, 22,560 to the hour. Atom bomb is from 1945 as both a noun and a verb;

Etymonline

Comment: Very nice. But as is often the case, answering is a matter of LMGTFY because OP doesn't know where/how to look.  HotLicks said it well.